# Нужно чтобы при нажатии на 2ю неделю (вторая кнопка) список кнопок внизу менялся на другой. Как это реализовать?

Tags: android, android-button

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Есть две кнопки. 1я неделя и 2я неделя. При нажатии на них, нижние кнопки должны меняться, в зависимости от нажатой кнопки. Как это сделать? Заранее Спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если это просто кнопки то можно использовать либо button.setVisiblity( ) и заменять эти кнопки на другие либо просто менять текст на кнопках а в onClick() проверять какая неделя выбрана.